# Change padding to text-indent in tinymce

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I'm using indent property in my tinymce configuration, but it works really strange - instead in indenting (btw, the property is called indent), it adds some padding. So this is how my tinymce instance is configured:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: '#mypanel',
    plugins: ["textcolor code"],
    toolbar: "undo redo | fontselect fontsizeselect | sizeselect | bold italic underline | forecolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | indent | code",
    fontsize_formats: "8px 10px 12px 14px 18px 24px 36px"
});
```

And this is what I see, when I press indent and check the sourcecode:

```
<p style="padding-left: 30px;">Hello world</p>
```

So, how can I change it to:

```
<p style="text-indent: 30px;">Hello world</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Possible workaround:

```
style_formats: [
    {title:'Indent', selector:'p', styles:{'text-indent':'30px'}}
],
style_formats_merge: true,
```

or

```
style_formats: [
    {title:'Indent', selector:'p', classes:'tindent'}
],
style_formats_merge: true,
content_css: 'my_styles.css', //define 'p.tindent' in the css file
```

Final answer: adds a new style-format (styleselect) and a button (tindent_bttn)

```
// id_ is not a selector(no '#'), but the simple element id
function tinymce_init(id_) {
    var settings = {
        ...
        style_formats: [
            {title:'Indent', selector:'p', classes:'tindent'},
        ],
        style_formats_merge: true,
        toolbar1:'... styleselect | tindent_bttn',
        toolbar2:'...',
        content_css:'my_styles.css',
        formats: {
            tindent_format:{selector:'p', classes:'tindent'},
        },
        ...
    };

    var editor = new tinymce.Editor(id_, settings, tinymce.EditorManager);
    editor.addButton('tindent_bttn', {
        text:'Indent',
        tooltip:'Indent',
        onclick:function() {
            editor.execCommand('mceToggleFormat', false, 'tindent_format');
        },
        onpostrender:function() {
            var btn = this;
            editor.formatter.formatChanged('tindent_format', function(state) {
                btn.active(state);
            });
        }
    });
    editor.render();

    return editor;
}
```

Documentation:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-formatting/
https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/creating-a-custom-button/
https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/